# Web3.js: account.signTransaction is too slow

Tags: web3js, javascript, bsc

I'm developing a swap bot to swap tokens on BSC using PancakeSwap router. so this is my code

```
      import {account, web3} from '../index.js';

      const timeOut = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000 + 100);
      let swapMethod = routerContract.methods.swapExactETHForTokens(
        0,
        [db.wbnb, token],
        account.address,
        timeOut
      );
      let encodedData = swapMethod.encodeABI();
    
      const tx = {
        from: account.address,
        to: db.router,
        gas: 500000,
        gasPrice: '5000000000',
        data: encodedData,
        value: web3.utils.toWei(amount),
      };

      // Sign transaction
      const signedTX = await account.signTransaction(tx);
```

I have a problem with signTransaction method. As you can see, I sign transactions locally with `account.signTransaction` but it takes more than 500ms to sign a transaction. Is it normal to take this long? Is there a way to make it faster?

Also I use a public RPC node to send transaction. Is it faster to use services like Ankr?

Comment: Signing transactions locally should not take that long. Are you sure you have local signing configured correctly? Please edit and add more details about your configuration on this question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added more info

Comment: I found out there was a problem with my Web3 setup.